# Best hashing algorithm in terms of hash collisions and performance for strings

Tags: c#, algorithm, hash

What would be the best hashing algorithm if we had the following priorities (in that order):

1. Minimal hash collisions
2. Performance

It doesn't have to be secure. Basically I'm trying to create an index based on a combination of properties of some objects. **All the properties are strings**.

Any references to c# implementations would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're trying to hash.

Comment: The following page has several implementations of general purpose hash functions that are efficient and exhibit minimal collisions: http://partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/index.html

Comment: @Matthieu N How are you able to get exactly 15 upvotes everytime you post this?

Comment: What makes you think that hashing performance will significantly affect the runtime of your application?  Do you have any performance measures to indicate this?  If you do, by all means spend some time on this.  If, however, you DON'T have any such indications, I submit that you're performing a faulty "optimization".

Comment: @nawfal How is this question a duplicate? This one is more theoretical and if you look at the most popular answer you cannot find this kind of advice in the other question which is much more specific. This is not a duplicate at all.

Comment: @dimitrisp you're right. Let me vote to reopen this. But what tempted me was seeing lot many similar related questions. What about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114085/fast-string-hashing-algorithm-with-low-collision-rates-with-32-bit-integer, though its a C++ question?

Comment: Be sure to specify a hash function that maps equivalent collections of `properties` to the same value. (There may be things about your `properties` that should be ignored, e.g., sequence, multiplicity, or case. Gets no better with colour vs. hue vs. color …)

Comment: I recommend BCrypt. It isn't the best, but it's a nice balance of security with ease of implementation. I wrote an article here: http://davismj.me/blog/bcrypt/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Forget about the term "best". No matter which hash algorithm anyone might come up with, unless you have a very limited set of data that needs to be hashed, every algorithm that performs very well on average can become completely useless if only being fed with the right (or from your perspective "wrong") data.

Instead of wasting too much time thinking about how to get the hash more collision-free without using too much CPU time, I'd rather start thinking about "How to make collisions less problematic". E.g. if every hash bucket is in fact a table and all strings in this table (that had a collision) are sorted alphabetically, you can search within a bucket table using binary search (which is only O(log n)) and that means, even when every second hash bucket has 4 collisions, your code will still have decent performance (it will be a bit slower compared to a collision free table, but not that much). One big advantage here is that if your table is big enough and your hash is not too simple, two strings resulting in the same hash value will usually look completely different (hence the binary search can stop comparing strings after maybe one or two characters on average; making every compare very fast).

Actually I had a situation myself before where searching directly within a sorted table using binary search turned out to be faster than hashing! Even though my hash algorithm was simple, it took quite some time to hash the values. Performance testing showed that only if I get more than about 700-800 entries, hashing is indeed faster than binary search. However, as the table could never grow larger than 256 entries anyway and as the average table was below 10 entries, benchmarking clearly showed that on every system, every CPU, the binary search was faster. Here, the fact that usually already comparing the first byte of the data was enough to lead to the next bsearch iteration (as the data used to be very different in the first one to two byte already) turned out as a big advantage.

So to summarize: I'd take a decent hash algorithm, that doesn't cause too many collisions on average and is rather fast (I'd even accept some more collisions, if it's just very fast!) and rather optimize my code how to get the smallest performance penalty once collisions do occur (and they will! They will unless your hash space is at least equal or bigger than your data space and you can map a unique hash value to every possible set of data).

Comment: Good advice when it comes to hashtables, but not for other uses of hashes (e.g. detecting if items are identical without keeping a copy of the other item).

Comment: @dbkk: You are right, if you need to detect duplicates without keeping the date around, you would need a collision free hash... in theory. In practice you just use MD5 or SHA1, since these hashes are very good (albeit slow) and chances of collisions very, very low. For implementing a hashtable, though, both algorithms are way too slow and produce way too big hash values (32 bit hashes are ideal for hashtables, in some exceptional cases you may need 64 bit values; anything bigger than that is just waste of time).

Answer (score 17):

As [Nigel Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251346/best-hashing-algorithm-in-terms-of-hash-collisions-and-performance#251361) indicated, there's no such thing as the 'best' hash function, as it depends on the data characteristics of what you're hashing as well as whether or not you need cryptographic quality hashes.

That said, here are some pointers:

- Since the items you're using as input to the hash are just a set of strings, you could simply combine the hashcodes for each of those individual strings.  I've seen the following pseudo-code suggested to do this, but I don't know of any particular analysis of it:

  ```
  int hashCode = 0;

  foreach (string s in propertiesToHash) {
      hashCode = 31*hashCode + s.GetHashCode();
  }
  ```

  According to [this article](http://www.themissingdocs.net/wordpress/?m=200607), System.Web has an internal method that combines hashcodes using

  ```
  combinedHash = ((combinedHash << 5) + combinedHash) ^ nextObj.GetHashCode();
  ```

  I've also seen code that simply xor's the hashcodes together, but that seems like a bad idea to me (though I again have no analysis to back this up). If nothing else, you end up with a collision if the same strings are hashed in a different order.
- I've used FNV to good effect:  http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/
- Paul Hsieh has a decent article: http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html
- Another nice article by Bob Jenkins that was originally published in 1997 in Doctor Dobb's Journal (the linked article has updates): http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html

Comment: MurmurHash2 is very fast and well-distributed.  http://murmurhash.googlepages.com/

Answer (score 8):

There is no one single optimum hashing algorithm.  If you have a known input domain you can use a perfect-hashing generator such as [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) to generate a hashing algorithm that will get a 100% rate on that particular input set.  Otherwise, there is no 'right' answer to this question.

Comment: No, but there are some wrong ones.  Some hashes just perform poorly in terms of distribution, not to mention execution time.

Answer (score 8):

I am going to be lame here and give a more theoretical response rather a pin-pointing answer but please take the value in it.

First there are two distinct problems :

a. Collision probability
b. Performance of hashing (i.e.: time, cpu-cycles etc.)

The two problems are mildly corellated. They are not perfectly correlated.

Problem a deals with the difference between the hashee and the resulted hash spaces. When you hash a 1KB file (1024 bytes) file and the hash has 32 bytes there will be :

1,0907481356194159294629842447338e+2466 (i.e. a number with 2466 zeros) possible combinations of input files

and the hash space will have

1,1579208923731619542357098500869e+77 (i.e. a number with 77 zeros)

The difference IS HUGE. there are 2389 zeros difference between them. THERE WILL BE COLLISIONS (a collision is a special case when two DIFFERENT input files will have the exact same hash) since we are reducing 10^2466 cases to 10^77 cases.

The only way to minimize collison risk is to enlarge the hash space and therefore to make the hahs longer. Ideally the hash will have the file length but this is somehow moronic.

---

The second problem is performance. This only deals with the algorithm of the hash. Ofcourse that a longer hash will most probably require more cpu cycles but a smarter algorithm might not. I have no clear case answer for this question. It's just too tough.

However you can benchmark/measure different hashing implementations and draw pre-conclusions from this.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 3):

The simple hashCode used by Java's String class might show a suitable algorithm.

Below is the "GNU Classpath" implementation. (License: GPL)

```
  /**
   * Computes the hashcode for this String. This is done with int arithmetic,
   * where ** represents exponentiation, by this formula:<br>
   * <code>s[0]*31**(n-1) + s[1]*31**(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]</code>.
   *
   * @return hashcode value of this String
   */
  public int hashCode()
  {
    if (cachedHashCode != 0)
      return cachedHashCode;

    // Compute the hash code using a local variable to be reentrant.
    int hashCode = 0;
    int limit = count + offset;
    for (int i = offset; i < limit; i++)
      hashCode = hashCode * 31 + value[i];
    return cachedHashCode = hashCode;
  }
```

Comment: Performance-wise, I don't think this is a good choice going forward. Despite historical praise of it being "good" (this code dates to at least 1981), it falls short of optimal collision rates, and also has poor uniformity. It works okay in hash tables, but today we can afford modern hash codes with more complex math and more output bits.

Answer (score 2):

You can get both using the Knuth hash function [described here](http://www.concentric.net/~Ttwang/tech/inthash.htm).

It's extremely fast assuming a power-of-2 hash table size -- just one multiply, one shift, and one bit-and.  More importantly (for you) it's great at minimizing collisions (see [this analysis](http://blog.clawpaws.net/post/2007/04/22/Good-Hash-Functions)).

Some other good algorithms are described [here](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/classes/hmc.cs070.200101/homework10/hashfuncs.html).

Comment: He's hashing strings, not ints.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward way of implementing it yourself: http://www.devcodenote.com/2015/04/collision-free-string-hashing.html

Here is a snippet from the post:

if say we have a character set of capital English letters, then the length of the character set is 26 where A could be represented by the number 0, B by the number 1, C by the number 2 and so on till Z by the number 25. Now, whenever we want to map a string of this character set to a unique number , we perform the same conversion as we did in case of the binary format

Comment: Yea that works, but it needs lot of calculation power.

Answer (score 1):

"Murmurhash" is pretty good on both performance and collisions.

The mentioned thread at "softwareengineering.stackexchange" has some tests and Murmur wins.

I wrote my own C# port of MurmurHash 2 to .NET and tested it on a list of 466k English words, got 22 collisions.

The results and implementation are here: https://github.com/jitbit/MurmurHash.net (disclaimer, I'm involved with this open source project!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Cuckoo Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing).

> Lookup requires inspection of just two
> locations in the hash table, which
> takes constant time in the worst case
> (see Big O notation). This is in
> contrast to many other hash table
> algorithms, which may not have a
> constant worst-case bound on the time
> to do a lookup.

I think that fits into your criteria of collisions and performance.  It appears that the tradeoff is that this type of hash table can only get 49% full.

Comment: That's the algorithm used for the hashtable itself, *after* you've calculated the hash. The question is about how to calculate a good hash.

Comment: Jon Skeet has spoken. You failed. :P