# What is the best 32bit hash function for short strings (tag names)?

Tags: algorithm, hash, tags, 32-bit

What is the best 32bit hash function for relatively short strings?

Strings are tag names that consist of English letters, numbers, spaces and some additional characters (`#`, `$`, `.`, ...). For example: `Unit testing`, `C# 2.0`.

I am looking for 'best' as in 'minimal collisions', performance is not important for my goals.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251346/best-hashing-algorithm-in-terms-of-hash-collisions-and-performance

Comment: Not completely so, because my question is more specific in terms of hash size and ignores performance. Also I am not just looking for _a_ hash function, I am looking for a meaningful choice -- I know there are CRC32 and FNV32, but which is better for my domain?

Comment: Is your tag list fixed to a set of strings or it will grow dynamically over time?

Comment: Tags are added by people so I can't predict them (but there are length and character limits).

Comment: @Andrey: What are the limits?

Comment: Max length: 20, current character set: `[A-Za-z\d\.#$@\-\ ]` (this can grow _slightly_ if I notice some useful symbol I missed).

Comment: The following page has several implementations of general purpose hash functions that are efficient and exhibit minimal collisions: http://partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/index.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If performance isn't important, simply take a secure hash such as MD5 or SHA1, and truncate its output to 32 bits. This will give you a distribution of hash codes that's indistinguishable from random.

Comment: md5 is perfect for this scenario

Comment: MD4 (see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1320 ) may be even better, since it is slightly simpler to implement than MD5. Note that neither MD4 nor MD5 is indistinguishable from random (both were "cryptographically broken") but they still are close enough for the purpose at hand.

Comment: Do you think it would have less collisions than Nick D's answer? I am somewhat undecided on what to approve/use.

Comment: @Thomas MD5 is broken in the sense that you can create a hash collision - two plaintexts that produce the same hash. That doesn't mean that the output of MD5 is distinguishable from randomness - there's no preimage attack against MD5. Which is easier to implement is kind of irrelevant, too - he'll almost certainly have a pre-made MD5 or SHA1 implementation in his language of choice.

Comment: @Andrey Secure hashes such as SHA1 and MD5 have the fewest collisions theoretically possible. Faster hashes such as the one Nick suggests are excellent where speed is important, but have more collisions. Your language of choice almost certainly has a pre-made implementation of MD5 or SHA1, too.

Comment: @Nick: attacks on MD5 are based on a differential path. By applying the input difference on an MD5 input, you have a small but higher-than-random probability of finding the expected difference in the output. This does not lead to a preimage attack, but it makes MD5 distinguishable from a random oracle. In the case of MD4, this was shown to be (academically) exploitable when used in HMAC (where collisions per se are no worry).

Comment: @Thomas I stand corrected. I didn't know that MD4 was broken even for HMACs - interesting result!

Comment: I have tested MD5, Sha1 and nomal CRC32, and they have almost the same collision rate, all about 0.23%. So MD5 and SHA1 do nothing better here. Is there any better hash than md5 and sha1?

Answer (score 29):

I'm not sure if it's the best choice, but here is a hash function for strings:

[*The Practice of Programming*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161586X) (HASH TABLES, pg. 57)

```c
/* hash: compute hash value of string */
unsigned int hash(char *str)
{
   unsigned int h;
   unsigned char *p;

   h = 0;
   for (p = (unsigned char*)str; *p != '\0'; p++)
      h = MULTIPLIER * h + *p;
   return h; // or, h % ARRAY_SIZE;
}
```

> **Empirically**, the values 31 and 37 have proven to be good choices for the multiplier in a hash function for ASCII strings.

Comment: Yep we use this exact hashing function with MULTIPLIER = 37 for strings and paths. Works well for us and I've yet to encounter a collision issue even after 2 years ( of course there's no guarantee we won't though )

Comment: This definitely looks simple enough. Any ideas why FNV was created if much simpler approach works?

Comment: @Andrey Shchekin, I use FNV hash when I deal with raw bytes (blobs). Perhaps, the above function yields better results specifically with strings. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Andrey + Nick D - Main reason we use the above algorithm is for speed. I know that performance wasn't a priority for Andrey so may be not be relevant. I've also used FNV32 but more hashing binary data like Nick D mentioned. Can't really compare like for like though - might be worth trying both out and seeing which one has the lower collision rate

Comment: I note that Perl's hash algorithm uses MULTIPLIER=33, and does an additional step at the end: h += (h >> 5) to improve distribution of lower-order bits.

Comment: This algorithm is one of variants discussed at http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html. It is unfortunately prone to basic hash-collision attacks (see [http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html]), since it is trivial to use substring based (see the referenced paper) collision calculation; but may work well if it is never used with externally-provided keys.

Answer (score 22):

I'm sorry for the very late reply on this. Earlier this year I composed a page titled [Hashing Short Strings](http://www.orthogonal.com.au/computers/hashstrings/) which might be helpful in this discussion. In summary, I found that CRC-32 and FNV-1a are superior for hashing short strings. They are efficient and produced widely distributed and collision free hashes in my tests. I was surprised to find that MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-3 produced small numbers of collisions when the output was *folded* down to 32-bits.

Comment: CRC32 is still the best answer here

Comment: I also think CRC32 should be the top-ranked answer

Comment: Actually, [CRC32 distribution is quite terrible compared to alternatives](https://github.com/rurban/smhasher). For 32 bit hashes, even a naive algorithm like product/rotation could produce better distribution for <8byte strings, and potentially be much faster. Speaking of which, [xxHash](https://create.stephan-brumme.com/xxhash/) does exactly that, but with much better distribution, and specifically optimized for modern processors (very much unlike CRC32). For hashing a large number of small strings with a lower number of collisions (such as when lexing), DJB2 is probably the best option.

Comment: @yyny The article posted above shows the DJB2 algorithm to produce 2220 collisions for 2 characters long strings and 70164 collisions for 3 characters long. Wouldn't a hash with much lower collision rates, for example FNV-1a, be better for hashing a large number of small strings?

Comment: When you say that CRC-32 and FNV-1 are superior for hashing short strings. I ask, in terms of what? And when you say they are efficient and produced widely distributed and collision free hashes in your tests, could you please let us know how many samples you used? Hundreds of thousands or even millions?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on your hardware.
On modern hardware, i.e. Intel/AMD with SSE4.2 or arm7 you should use the internal `_mm_crc32_uxx` intrinsics, as they are optimal for short strings. (For long keys also, but then better use Adler's threaded version, as in zlib)

On old or unknown hardware, either run-time probe for the SSE4.2 or CRC32 feature or just use one if the simple good hash functions. E.g. Murmur2 or City

An overview of quality and performance is here:
https://github.com/rurban/smhasher#smhasher

There are also all the implementations. Favored are https://github.com/rurban/smhasher/blob/master/crc32_hw.c and https://github.com/rurban/smhasher/blob/master/MurmurHash2.cpp

If you know the keys in advance, use a **perfect hash**, not a hash function. E.g. **gperf** or my **phash**: https://github.com/rurban/Perfect-Hash#name

Nowadays perfect hash generation via a c compiler is so fast, you can even create them on the fly, and dynaload it.

Comment: Update: Murmur2 and City cannot be called simple good hash functions anymore.
Fastest would be FNV1 or CRC32-C, better would be Metro or Farmhash.

Comment: SpookyHash64 still has the best avalanching/lowest collision rates out of all hash functions I have found, I would highly advice using it for robin hood hash maps, unless you have empirically found that other hash functions are better/faster. For small inputs I would recommend FNV1A or DJB2. SpookyHash has a pretty high setup cost clocking in at ~30 cycles. Metro/Farm/Murmur/City/xxHash/many others are great for fast, general purpose hashing, with lower setup times, but higher collisions rates. I wouldn't use them when low collision rates are important.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MaPrime2c` hash function:

```c
static const unsigned char sTable[256] =
{
  0xa3,0xd7,0x09,0x83,0xf8,0x48,0xf6,0xf4,0xb3,0x21,0x15,0x78,0x99,0xb1,0xaf,0xf9,
  0xe7,0x2d,0x4d,0x8a,0xce,0x4c,0xca,0x2e,0x52,0x95,0xd9,0x1e,0x4e,0x38,0x44,0x28,
  0x0a,0xdf,0x02,0xa0,0x17,0xf1,0x60,0x68,0x12,0xb7,0x7a,0xc3,0xe9,0xfa,0x3d,0x53,
  0x96,0x84,0x6b,0xba,0xf2,0x63,0x9a,0x19,0x7c,0xae,0xe5,0xf5,0xf7,0x16,0x6a,0xa2,
  0x39,0xb6,0x7b,0x0f,0xc1,0x93,0x81,0x1b,0xee,0xb4,0x1a,0xea,0xd0,0x91,0x2f,0xb8,
  0x55,0xb9,0xda,0x85,0x3f,0x41,0xbf,0xe0,0x5a,0x58,0x80,0x5f,0x66,0x0b,0xd8,0x90,
  0x35,0xd5,0xc0,0xa7,0x33,0x06,0x65,0x69,0x45,0x00,0x94,0x56,0x6d,0x98,0x9b,0x76,
  0x97,0xfc,0xb2,0xc2,0xb0,0xfe,0xdb,0x20,0xe1,0xeb,0xd6,0xe4,0xdd,0x47,0x4a,0x1d,
  0x42,0xed,0x9e,0x6e,0x49,0x3c,0xcd,0x43,0x27,0xd2,0x07,0xd4,0xde,0xc7,0x67,0x18,
  0x89,0xcb,0x30,0x1f,0x8d,0xc6,0x8f,0xaa,0xc8,0x74,0xdc,0xc9,0x5d,0x5c,0x31,0xa4,
  0x70,0x88,0x61,0x2c,0x9f,0x0d,0x2b,0x87,0x50,0x82,0x54,0x64,0x26,0x7d,0x03,0x40,
  0x34,0x4b,0x1c,0x73,0xd1,0xc4,0xfd,0x3b,0xcc,0xfb,0x7f,0xab,0xe6,0x3e,0x5b,0xa5,
  0xad,0x04,0x23,0x9c,0x14,0x51,0x22,0xf0,0x29,0x79,0x71,0x7e,0xff,0x8c,0x0e,0xe2,
  0x0c,0xef,0xbc,0x72,0x75,0x6f,0x37,0xa1,0xec,0xd3,0x8e,0x62,0x8b,0x86,0x10,0xe8,
  0x08,0x77,0x11,0xbe,0x92,0x4f,0x24,0xc5,0x32,0x36,0x9d,0xcf,0xf3,0xa6,0xbb,0xac,
  0x5e,0x6c,0xa9,0x13,0x57,0x25,0xb5,0xe3,0xbd,0xa8,0x3a,0x01,0x05,0x59,0x2a,0x46
};


#define PRIME_MULT 1717


unsigned int
maPrime2cHash (unsigned char *str, unsigned int len)
{
  unsigned int hash = len, i;


  for (i = 0; i != len; i++, str++)
    {

      hash ^= sTable[( *str + i) & 255];
      hash = hash * PRIME_MULT;
    }

  return hash;
}
```

and look at www.amsoftware.narod.ru/algo2.html for MaFastPrime, MaRushPrime, etc tests.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out murmurhash2. It is fast, also for small strings, and has a good mixing final step so it is even good mixed for very small strings.

Answer (score 0):

If it's rare that users add new tags, then you can use a perfect hash (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) that's recomputed each time a new tag is added. Of course, without knowing the problem you are really trying to solve, it's guesswork to figure out what you might do.

Answer (score 0):

If your program needs communicate with other system, it is better to use a algorithm which is well known. The quick & dirty way is **using first Several characters of md5 hash**. You don't need spend hours or days to invent wheels in your project.

The disadvantage is get much much high chance to collisions. However, if your hash is for a time-stamped session, or short life circule task. There is no problem to use that.