# 32 bit fast uniform hash function. Use MD5 / SHA1 and cut off 4 bytes?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best 32bit hash function for short strings (tag names)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351087/what-is-the-best-32bit-hash-function-for-short-strings-tag-names)

I need to hash many strings to 32bit (uint).

Can I just use MD5 or SHA1 and take 4 bytes from it? Or are there better alternatives?

There is no need for security or to care if one is cracked and so on.
I just need to hash fast and uniform to 32 bit. MD5 and SHA1 should be uniform.

But are there better (faster) build in alternatives I could use? If not, which of both would you use?

Here someone asked which one is better, but not for alternatives and there was a security matter (I don't care for security):
[How to Use SHA1 or MD5 in C#?(Which One is Better in Performance and Security for Authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756188/how-to-use-sha1-or-md5-in-cwhich-one-is-better-in-performance-and-security-fo?rq=1)

Comment: Would a CRC (or related) be good for this purpose?

Comment: Also what's wrong with `.GetHashCode()`?

Comment: .GetHashCode() can change through .Net versions, but I need the values to be constant. Also most of my strings are not short.

Comment: String.GetHashCode()'s return value also differs between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the .NET Framework, so really you shouldn't depend on it for anything more than in-process equality; if you ever have to persist a hash or use one generated by another process or runtime you should roll your own.

Comment: So you *are* going to be persisting this hashes longer than a process or not?

Comment: @32bitkid: Yes I am using them persistent. All Clients will have these hashes and I don't know which software or .Net version they have installed. And the hash calculation needs to be the same on all clients ands servers.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate:
1. I am asking regarding performance, the other is not
2. It is language depended (c#) the other question is not
3. The other questions are for short strings, but my strings are not short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If security does not play a role, generating a hash with a cryptographic hash function (such as MD5 or SHA1) and taking 4 bytes from it works. But they are slower than various non-cryptographic hash functions, as these functions are primarily designed for security, not speed.

Have a look at non-cryptographic hash functions such as [FNV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) or [Murmur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash).

- <strike>Non-Cryptographic Hash Function Zoo</strike>

  - <strike>Performance Graphs</strike>
- [MurMurHash3, an ultra fast hash algorithm for C# / .NET](http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/08/murmurhash3-ultra-fast-hash-algorithm.html)

**Edit:** The floodyberry.com domain is now registered by a domain parking service - removed dead links

Answer (score 9):

Do you need a cryptographic-strength hash? If all you need is 32 bits I bet not.

Try the Fowler-Noll-Vo hash. It's fast, has good distribution and avalanche effect, and is generally acceptable for hashtables, checksums etc:

```
    public static uint To32BitFnv1aHash(this string toHash, 
       bool separateUpperByte = false)
    {
        IEnumerable<byte> bytesToHash;

        if (separateUpperByte)
            bytesToHash = toHash.ToCharArray()
                .Select(c => new[] { (byte)((c - (byte)c) >> 8), (byte)c })
                .SelectMany(c => c);
        else
            bytesToHash = toHash.ToCharArray()
                .Select(Convert.ToByte);

        //this is the actual hash function; very simple
        uint hash = FnvConstants.FnvOffset32;

        foreach (var chunk in bytesToHash)
        {
            hash ^= chunk;
            hash *= FnvConstants.FnvPrime32;
        }

        return hash;
    }

public static class FnvConstants
{
    public static readonly uint FnvPrime32 = 16777619;
    public static readonly ulong FnvPrime64 = 1099511628211;
    public static readonly uint FnvOffset32 = 2166136261;
    public static readonly ulong FnvOffset64 = 14695981039346656037;
}
```

This is really useful for creating semantically equatable hashes for GetHashCode, based on a string digest of each object (a custom ToString() or otherwise). You can overload this to take any `IEnumerable<byte>` making it suitable for checksumming stream data etc. If you ever need a 64-bit hash (ulong), just copy the function and replace the constants used with the 64-bit constants. Oh, one more thing; the hash (as most do) rely on unchecked integer overflow; never run this hash in a "checked" block, or it will be virtually guaranteed to throw out exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and yet good algorithm for strings is as follow:

```
int Hash(string s)
{
  int res = 0; 
  for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
  {
     res += (i * str[i]) % int.MaxValue;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Obviously, this is absolutely not a secured hash algorithm but it is fast (really fast) returns 32 bit and as far as I know, is uniform (I've tried it for many algorithmic challenges with good results).

Not for use to hash password or any sensible data.

Comment: This algorithm has *extremely* poor avalanche characteristics. A simple algorithm could find a colliding plaintext in seconds simply by solving for the largest C (repeating character decimal value) and N (string length) where `CN(N+1)/2 < hash` and `minLength < N < maxLength`, then incrementing character values, rightmost first, staying under the target hash and within the printable character codes, until the hash matches exactly.

Comment: As I said, speed is the point. Security is not. This is only good for fast retrieval of strings using hash tables.