# How do you pick/what is a radix in a hash function?

Tags: c++, hash, radix

I have seen the Radix of 37 being used a lot, I'm just wondering what it stands for. I'm converting strings to numbers for a hash function and know that we will use a Radix of 37 have *ascii* values of the digits, I just don't know why we selected 37 as the radix, is this just random?

I know that a Radix  = base of a number system.

I see that when we just use numbers into a hash() function we use a radix of 10..because that what the base of the numbers we will use.. simple.. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

Strings - I can see that the base for a string that has all capital letters(no space I'm assuming) is 26... Because there are 26 letters in the alphabet and we will represents each one with a number 0 = A, 1 = B, 2 = C, etc.

What the heck does 37 mean, I read something about 31 or 33.
What I've read and understood is that we use a different radix from 26 when we have to deal with spaces, lowercase letters, numerals, and special cases.

From all the patterns I see I would have figured that if we would translate the String into ASCII code we would use the number of characters in that ASCII has which is like 127, I think.

Comment: Take a look at, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351087/what-is-the-best-32bit-hash-function-for-short-strings-tag-names

Comment: But, why 37?, is it because it is the number that seems to do random and equal distribution? Someone just tried out different numbers and this one seems to work a lot

Comment: I have this passage from a text,"  we are not trying to preserve the purity of a number in a different base, but rather, the property of random and equal distribution of numbers." I think that is the key for me to understand this, I just don;t know what it means.

Comment: From the second answer, "Empirically, the values 31 and 37 have proven to be good choices for the multiplier in a hash function for ASCII strings". It's fast, simple, and does a pretty good job.

Comment: Okay, So from what I see there is no longer a "pattern" of A=0, B=1, C=2, etc...That no longer matters. But what the main focus is a multiplier that provides equal distribution of numbers? and 31..37 have been found to dot he job.

Comment: It's a big subject but that's the basic idea. A prime multiplier that doesn't divide the size of the container provide decent distribution and are simple defaults for things like strings.

Answer (score 0):

Radixes in hash functions are generally either prime numbers, for best distribution, or powers of two minus one, for fastest computation.

31 and 37 are commonly used prime numbers for *multiplication,* during hash functions, not as radixes: they're too small.