# stl map performance?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, profiling

I am using `map<MyStruct, I*> map1;`. Apparently 9% of my total app time is spent in there. Specifically on one line of one of my major functions. The map isn't very big (<1k almost always, <20 is common).

Is there an alternative implementation i may want to use? I think i shouldn't write my own but i could if i thought it was a good idea.

Additional info: I always check before adding an element. If a key exist I need to report a problem. Than after a point i will be using map heavily for lookups and will not add any more elements.

Comment: Without source code, we can't really tell. Also look at the version of `insert` which returns a pair (this will answer your second question)

Comment: Could you share information on your compare function on `MyStruct` that the map uses as well?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about what are you doing within the mentioned function? Since the lookup complexity of map is O(log n), I'm not sure where an improvement shall come from.

Comment: Are you profiling with optimisations on?

Answer (score 59):

First you need to understand what a map is and what the operations that you are doing represent. A `std::map` is a balanced binary tree, lookup will take `O( log N )` operations, each of which is a comparison of the keys plus some extra that you can ignore in most cases (pointer management). Insertion takes roughly the same time to locate the point of insertion, plus allocation of the new node, the actual insertion into the tree and rebalancing. The complexity is again `O( log N )` although the hidden constants are higher.

When you try to determine whether an key is in the map prior to insertion you are incurring the cost of the lookup and if it does not succeed, the same cost to locate the point of insertion. You can avoid the extra cost by using `std::map::insert` that return a pair with an iterator and a bool telling you whether the insertion actually happened or the element was already there.

Beyond that, you need to understand how costly it is to compare your keys, which falls out of what the question shows (`MyStruct` could hold just one `int` or a thousand of them), which is something you need to take into account.

Finally, it might be the case that a `map` is not the most efficient data structure for your needs, and you might want to consider using either an `std::unordered_map` (hash table) that has expected constant time insertions (if the hash function is not *horrible*) or for small data sets even a plain ordered array (or `std::vector`) on which you can use binary search to locate the elements (this will reduce the number of allocations, at the cost of more expensive insertions, but if the held types are small enough it might be worth it)

As always with performance, measure and then try to understand where the time is being spent. Also note that a 10% of the time spent in a particular function or data structure might be a lot or almost nothing at all, depending on what your application is. For example, if your application is just performing lookups and insertions into a data set, and that takes only a 10% of the CPU you have a lot to optimize everywhere else!

Comment: Excellent answer. One suggestion was unordered (hash) may be bad since the size of the table is small. I'll definitely use insert in my other location. You hit on all the important points

Comment: Alternatively to a blind insert you could use `lower_bound`, check the key, and then use hinted insertion (if you want to avoid a potentially expensive object construction).

Comment: The struct is actually a quick wrapper template i wrote which holds T*. The point is so ops like `<` and `==` will do `*ptr OP *other` so it doesn't compare by ptr address. It makes my life immensely easier when using containers. Thats another good hint. +1 @KerrekSB

Answer (score 10):

Probably it will be quicker to just do an `insert` and check if the `pair.second` is `false` if key already exists:

like this

```
if ( myMap.insert( make_pair( MyStruct, I* ) ).second == false)
{
  // report error
}
else
  // inserted new value
```

... rather than doing a `find` call every time.

Comment: Excellent idea. Although adding memebers is not the line with the performance problem. I'll add that in and take a look at the performance

Comment: If you defer the find to whether you actually have a clash you probably eliminate a shedload of lookups that are not necessary unless you are doing something rather odd and generating more duplicate values than unique ones. The `insert` method I have detailed returns a pair with `first` being an iterator to the new value or duplicate value, the second is a boolean with `true` meaning success and `false` meaning duplicate entry.

Comment: I feel a bit silly not doing inserts this way. I must have been in a rush or thought it was throwaway code.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `map` you could try [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which uses hash keys, instead of a tree, to find elements. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197015/237483) gives some hints when to prefer `unordered_map` over `map`.

Comment: For small collections, hash-maps are *usually* slower then red-black-trees, so I expect its usage in this case to only have a negative affect.

Comment: @amit: Even for a small collection with 20 elements, [this simple comparison](http://ideone.com/YupK4) -- under the restriction of a simple key type -- gives me a better performance for the `unordered_set`. A real comparison would include `MyStruct` and a hash function for it.

Comment: I looked at unordered_map. After reading the error message (its big...) i realize i need to implement a hashing function. I have no idea how to do that. How do i hash a char*? One that can be 1 to 20chars long (or more)

Comment: @acidzombie24: The Standard Library provides the template `std::hash` which you can use as [hash function for `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash). Maybe you don't need to explicitly specify it as template argument to `unordered_map`, if you switch from `char*` to `std::string`. There is also [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/114085/237483) asking for a string-hashing-function.

Answer (score 5):

It might be a long shot, but for small collections, sometimes the most critical factor is the [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) performance.

Since `std::map` implements a Red-Black Tree, which is [AFAIK] not very cache-efficient - maybe implementing the map as a `std::vector<pair<MyStruct,I*>>` would be a good idea, and use binary search there [instead of map look-ups], at the very least it should be efficient once you start only looking up [stop inserting elements], since the `std::vector` is more likely to fit in cache than the `map`.

This factor [cpu-cache] is usually neglected and hidden as constant in the big O notation, but for large collections it might have major effect.

Comment: I'd probably have a class that uses two vectors internally rather than a pair and make it look similar to a map.

Comment: @acidzombie24: The `pair` is only a suggestion. Regarding two vectors: I agree, it will probably be indeed even better then a `vector` of `pair`s [less fields -> less memory usage -> more likely that the entire map will fit in cache]. The answer aimed to only to emphasize the important of cache on small collections, and to remind it is usually much more important then big O notation for these, since the constants should not be neglected.

Comment: We have seen big improvements in our code in certain cases when switching from map to vector. We suspect the caching performance is much greater with vector.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are using the map, you're doing lookups on the basis of a `MyStruct` instance and depending on your particular implementation, the required comparison may or may not be costly.

Comment: hmm, i don't think i need it in a specific order. I realize most of the code was checking if the two variables are null and i dount think it ever is. Just removing that check made it fast enough to disappear from the profiler(i'm surprised). If it shows up again i'll play with the compare function more. +1 and possibly accept.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an alternative implementation i may want to use? I think i shouldn't write my own but i could if i thought it was a good idea.

If you understand the problem well enough, you should detail how your implementation will be superior.

Is `map` the proper structure? If so, then your standard library's implementation will likely be of good quality (well optimized).

Can `MyStruct` comparison be simplified?

Where is the problem -- resizing? lookup?

Have you minimized copy and assign costs for your structures?

Comment: Problem: Lookup. Proper Struct: Maybe. I need to find a struct by key (which needs to compare with other struct) and the interface object associated with it. I dont think order is a problem since it typically tiny. Copy/Assign: Well, i assign by copying a ptr. Its immutable so i dont have to worry about it being deleted.

Comment: I was checking if both structs are null in my cmp func. Removing it made it fast enough to not show up anymore. +1 for overall answer.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, without proper code, there is little universal answers to give you. However, if `MyStruct` is really huge the stack copying may be costly. Perhaps it makes sense to store pointers to `MyStruct` and implement your own compare mechanism:

```
template <typename T> struct deref_cmp {
  bool operator()(std::shared_ptr<T> lhs, std::shared_ptr<T> rhs) const {
    return *lhs < *rhs;
  }
};

std::map<std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>, I*, deref_cmp<MyStruct>> mymap;
```

However, this is something you will have to profile. It *might* speed things up.

You would look up an element like this

```
template <typename T> struct NullDeleter {
  void operator()(T const*) const {}
};
// needle being a MyStruct
mymap.find(std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>(&needle,NullDeleter()));
```

Needless to say, there is more potential to optimise.

Comment: MyStruct is actually T* where T is a template ;). See my first comment to Johann Gerell answer

Comment: Well, in that case you don't have to bother with this redirection.

Comment: yep. so +1 for the suggestion anyways :)