# What is a fast data-structure to implement a pair storage, as specified here?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, data-structures, hash

I am trying to implement a storage of pairs of values. It must expose a simple API: `newPair, get, remove, isMember`. A value can consist of either a `4-bit int` or a pointer to another pair. So, for example:

```
Pointer a = API.newPair(13,12);
Pointer b = API.newPair(a,7);
Pointer c = API.newPair(2,b);
Pointer d = API.newPair(a,7);
```

And so on. There is just one caveat, though: a pair must never be stored twice. If you try to add a pair that already exists, it just returns the existing pointer. So, for example, on the code above, `b == d`.

My naive implementation involved a stack of pairs. Each time a new pair was added, I just iterated the stack and, if I found the pair there, I returned its position. If not, I added a new element to the stack and returned the stack size. Now I need to make it as fast as possible. My current idea is to just use a hash-table instead of a stack.

So, the question is: what is a fast way to implement this?

Comment: Maybe a hash table, e.g. `std::unoedered_set<YourPairType>`. You just need to implement a hash function and an equality comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bijection NxN -> N given by [Cantor Pairing Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function)

[image]

can be used if N is an infinite set. It works by consecutive assigning elements of NxN to N this way:

[image]

When x,y are non negative integers the mapping introduced in [ElegantPairing](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf) may be used

```
x >= y ? x * x + x + y : x + y * y;  where x, y >= 0
```

which works by assigning values along the edges of a squere.

### The code

```
int cantor_pairing( int k1, int k2) {
    return 0.5 * ( k1 + k2) * ( k1 + k2 + 1) + k2;
}

int szuzik_pairing( int x, int y) {
    if( x < 0 || y < 0) return -1;
    return x >= y ? x * x + x + y : x + y * y;
}
```

---

Even if your integers were joint uniformly distributed you couldn't have been used just the mapping

(x,y) -> x

i.e. completely ignoring the second of them. This is because on  a square NxN f(x,y) would be 1/N^2 but marginal distribution f_y(x) = 1/N and this would be a probability of a collision. 
After all, most probably this is not the case, because user will more frequently choose small numbers then large.

Comment: Wow, that answer was so spot-in I can't even. Were you looking my other questions?

Comment: I was only looking at "What is a fast hash function for pairs of ints?"

Comment: The question just before that was a completely unrelated question about godel numbering and enumeration of context-free-grammars. I just found it amazing that you actually gave me a great reference to that question too.

Comment: Viclib I have read the question  "What is a fast hash function for pairs of ints?" posted by yourself about 30 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

If your pair has 4-bits elements, a char (= 8-bits long in 99% of cases) would be enough for storing a pair. A little comment: with a 4-bit long (signed) integer, your range of allowed values is: [-7, 8], but, in your example, you haved used the values 12 and 13, so, I understand your pair is composed of two 4-bit unsigned integers.

```
// a and b should be values between 0 and 15.
// Otherwise, the behaviour is undefined
// (or if you want, you could control the values of
//  a/b and throw an exception in the opposite case).
Pair APIClass::newPair(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    char c = (char(a) << 4) | char(b);

    return Pair(c); // `typedef char Pair;` p.e. 
}
```

Assuming  `unsigned`s `a` and `b` are between 0 and 15, in binary:

```
a ≡ 0000000000000000000000000000xxxx // 32-bits
b ≡ 0000000000000000000000000000yyyy // 32-bits
```

and the goal is:

```
Pair ≡ xxxxyyyy // 8-bits
```

So, the following transformations take place:

```
// For a
0000000000000000000000000000xxxx => conversion to char
0000xxxx                         => 4-bits left-shift
xxxx0000

// For b
0000000000000000000000000000yyyy => conversion to char
0000yyyy

// Result:

      xxxx0000
  |   0000yyyy
--------------
      xxxxyyyy
```

and that's all.

Finally, if you mean 4-bytes `int`s, same reasoning applies but using a `long long int` as placeholder (although not in every architecture a `long long int` is 64-bits long).

Comment: That's great for the 4-bit case, but what if it's a pointer to an other pair?

Comment: @harold Copy its contents. The condition of "don't storing twice" only makes sense if the storage of a pair is noticeably bigger than a pointer. In this case, a pointer is four times bigger than a `char`. The use of auxiliary data structures and overheads for searching operations has no logic in this case.

Comment: Copy its contents where? Now it's 12 bits, or 16, or 20, etc - obviously you'll run into trouble there. Also, a DAG of nodes can be exponentially smaller than its tree-ified version.

Comment: @harold "Copy its contents where?" In the new returning pair. If your pair is a `typedef` of `char`, with `return *pointer_to_pair` would be enough.

Comment: It's not a pair of 4-bit integers or a pointer, it's a pair of (4-bit integer or pointer)

Comment: @harold If your integers are 12, 16 or 20 bit-long, you are describing then a completely different problem.

Comment: Ah that is a good and clever way to store 4-bit pairs, but the whole issue is that most of the pairs will actually be using pointers, not primitives. The use case is for storing binary trees of 4-bit uints with shared branches, so, for example, `(1 (2 (3 (4 5))) (2 (3 (4 5))))` - this binary tree has `(2 (3 (4 5)))` twice. Storing it once should suffice.

Comment: @Viclib ahhhhh ok. I've misunderstood the problem them.

Comment: @Viclib use boost::flyweight and left the problem to others :P

Comment: But I insist in my view that, for so little objects, it isn't worth spending time resources for avoiding repetitions, even more when the require storage for implementing that "avoidance" could spend finally, in sum, more storage.

Comment: Who said it is little objects? This involves gigabyte long binary trees of those 4-bit values, that are being added, removed and processed in realtime. The savings can be huge. I'll take a look on boost::flyweight, thanks.

Comment: @Viclib, ok you're right. For 4-bit integers and such requirements, the probability of repetitions are high.