# Good Hash Function for Strings

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, hashcode

I'm trying to think up a good hash function for strings.  And I was thinking it might be a good idea to sum up the unicode values for the first five characters in the string (assuming it has five, otherwise stop where it ends).  Would that be a good idea, or is it a bad one?

I am doing this in Java, but I wouldn't imagine that would make much of a difference.

Comment: Good hash functions depend heavily on the input to the hash, and the requirements of the algorithm.  Such a hash will not be very good if all your strings start with the same five characters, for example.  It will also tend to result in a normal distribution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [98153](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98153/whats-the-best-hashing-algorithm-to-use-on-a-stl-string-when-using-hash-map)

Comment: Why can't you use `String`'s own `hashCode()`?

Comment: @WhirlWind, true, I'm not sure what the strings will have, other than that it will probably english text.

Comment: @Barl, mainly because my professor told us to implement our own hash functor...and the reason I didn't want to use Java's, was because it was generic, and I would imagine a more specific hash functor would be better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best hashing algorithm to use on a stl string when using hash\_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98153/whats-the-best-hashing-algorithm-to-use-on-a-stl-string-when-using-hash-map)

Comment: I have just been fighting against a mysterious bug for several hours. Turned out it's a hash collision with `String.hashCode()`. Hashing to int seems a bad idea.

Comment: See also this Q&A with lots of good hash algorithms mentioned here: [hash function for string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7666509/4561887)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Usually hashes wouldn't do sums, otherwise `stop` and `pots` will have the same hash.

and you wouldn't limit it to the first n characters because otherwise house and houses would have the same hash.

Generally hashs take values and multiply it by a prime number (makes it more likely to generate unique hashes) So you could do something like:

```
int hash = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen; i++) {
    hash = hash*31 + charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: @jonathanasdf How can you say that it always gives you a unique hash key. Is there any mathematical proof ? I think we have to take mod of hash with another bigger prime number, otherwise overflow problem occurs.

Comment: @devsda He didn't say always unique, he said more likely to be unique. As for why, a quick search on google reveals this article: http://computinglife.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/why-do-hash-functions-use-prime-numbers/ explaining why 31 was used for Java string hashing. There is no mathematical proof given, but it does explain the general concept as to why primes work better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the idea of doing better hashing. Just to double check - The hashCode() return value will be used by Java to map to some table index before storing the object. So, if the hashCode() returns m, it does something like (m mod k) to get an index of the table of size k. Is that right?

Comment: This was amazing, you have no idea how much it helped. I understand that using 31 gives the best unique results, but is the 7 also the best possible? Or did you just pick a random prime number?

Comment: I decreased my collisions by taking the final result mod the length of the string. (Im working in python so I had to change it up a little bit)

Answer (score 162):

If it's a security thing, you could use Java crypto:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
messageDigest.update(stringToHash.getBytes());
String stringHash = new String(messageDigest.digest());
```

Comment: Nice. I have a machine-learning application, doing statistical NLP over a large corpus. After a few initial passes of morphological normalization on the original words in the text, I throw away the string values and use hash codes instead. Throughout my entire corpus, there are about 600,000 unique words, and using the default java hashcode function, I was getting about 3.5% collisions. But if I SHA-256 the string value and then generate a hashcode from the digested string, the collision ratio is less than 0.0001%. Thanks!

Comment: @benjismith One in a million is far too large... is "less than 0.0001%" an oblique way of saying "exactly 0"?  I really doubt that you saw a SHA-256 collision because that has never been observed, anywhere, ever; not even for 160-bit SHA-1.  If you have two strings that produce the same SHA-256, the security community would love to see them; you'll be world-famous... in a very obscure way.  See [Comparison of SHA Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions)

Comment: @TimSylvester, you misunderstood. I didn't find SHA-256 collisions. I computed the SHA-256 and then fed the resultant byte sequences into a typical Java "hashCode" function, because I needed a 32-bit hash. That's where I found the collisions. Nothing remarkable :)

Comment: Isn't there a difference between 'hashing' and 'encrypting'? I understand MessageDigest is a one way hashing function, right? Also, when I used the function, I got the hashed string as a lot of junk UTF characters when I opened the file in LibreOffice. Is it possible to get the hashed string as a random bunch of alphanumeric characters instead of junk UTF characters?

Comment: `String encryptedString` and `stringToEncrypt.getBytes()` refer to encryption, when this really is a hashing algorithm.

Comment: My generated values look like this: "��'x�-E#��G����]%�c�3��u�" , is this normal thing and can I rely on this?

Comment: if you need reasonable characters, try for instance base64 (I use apache commons)

Comment: you can convert the byte array into hex string to get an understandable string. here is how you do it. `new BigInteger(1,byteArr).toString(16)`

Answer (score 42):

You should probably use [String.hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()).

If you really want to implement hashCode yourself:

> Do not be tempted to exclude
>   significant parts of an object from
>   the hash code computation to improve
>   performance -- Joshua Bloch, Effective Java

Using only the first five characters is a *bad idea*. Think about hierarchical names, such as URLs: they will all have the same hash code (because they all start with "http://", which means that they are stored under the same bucket in a hash map, exhibiting terrible performance.

Here's a war story paraphrased on the String hashCode from "[Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)":

> The String hash function implemented
>   in all releases prior to 1.2 examined
>   at most sixteen characters, evenly
>   spaced throughout the string, starting
>   with the first character. For large
>   collections of hierarchical names,
>   such as URLs, this hash function
>   displayed terrible behavior.

Comment: If one is using a double-hashed collection, it may be worthwhile to have the first hash be really quick and dirty.  If one has a thousand long strings, half of which a are mapped by a crummy function to one particular value, and half of which are mapped to distinct values, performance in a single-hashed table would be bad, but performance in a double-hashed table, where the second hash examined the entire string, could be almost twice that of a singly-hashed table (since half the strings wouldn't have to be fully hashed).  None of the standard Java collections do double hashing, though.

Answer (score 18):

If you are doing this in Java then why are you doing it?  Just call `.hashCode()` on the string

Comment: I'm doing it as part of the class, and part of the assignment is to write up several different hash functions.  The professor told us to get outside help for the 'better' ones.

Comment: If you need your has to be consistent across JVM versions and implementations, you should not rely on `.hashCode()`. Rather, use some known algorithm.

Comment: The algorithm for `String::hashCode` is specified in the JDK, so it's as portable as the very existence of the class `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 13):

[Guava's `HashFunction`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/HashingExplained#hashfunction) ([javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashFunction.html)) provides decent non-crypto-strong hashing.

Answer (score 10):

This function provided by Nick is good but if you use new String(byte[] bytes) to make the transformation to String, it failed. You can use this function to do that.

```
private static final char[] hex = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

public static String byteArray2Hex(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(bytes.length * 2);
    for(final byte b : bytes) {
        sb.append(hex[(b & 0xF0) >> 4]);
        sb.append(hex[b & 0x0F]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String getStringFromSHA256(String stringToEncrypt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    messageDigest.update(stringToEncrypt.getBytes());
    return byteArray2Hex(messageDigest.digest());
}
```

May be this can help somebody

Comment: You could just pass the byte array to messageDigest.update().

Answer (score 5):

[FNV-1](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) is rumoured to be a good hash function for strings.

For long strings (longer than, say, about 200 characters), you can get good performance out of the [MD4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320) hash function. As a cryptographic function, it was broken about 15 years ago, but for non cryptographic purposes, it is still very good, and surprisingly fast. In the context of Java, you would have to convert the 16-bit `char` values into 32-bit words, e.g. by grouping such values into pairs. A fast implementation of MD4 in Java can be found in [sphlib](http://www.crypto-hash.fr/modules/wfdownloads/singlefile.php?cid=13&lid=10). Probably overkill in the context of a classroom assignment, but otherwise worth a try.

Comment: This hash function is so much better then the one that comes with java.

Answer (score 4):

```
// djb2 hash function
unsigned long hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}
```

[source](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html)
[Logic behind djb2 hash function - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579721/can-anybody-explain-the-logic-behind-djb2-hash-funcition)

Comment: I think it's just a prime number to start at, so that we have fewer collisions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the industry standard implementations, I'd look at [java.security.MessageDigest](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).

"Message digests are secure one-way hash functions that take arbitrary-sized data and output a fixed-length hash value."

Answer (score 1):

sdbm:this algorithm was created for sdbm (a public-domain reimplementation of ndbm) database library

```
static unsigned long sdbm(unsigned char *str)
{   
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int c;
    while (c = *str++)
            hash = c + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;

    return hash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         public String hashString(String s) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    byte[] hash = null;
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        hash = md.digest(s.getBytes());

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; ++i) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(hash[i]);
        if (hex.length() == 1) {
            sb.append(0);
            sb.append(hex.charAt(hex.length() - 1));
        } else {
            sb.append(hex.substring(hex.length() - 2));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will avoid any collision and it will be fast until we use the shifting in calculations.

```
 int k = key.length();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < k-1 ; i++){
        sum += key.charAt(i)<<(5*i);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Its a good idea to work with odd number when trying to develop a good hast function for string. this function takes a string and return a index value, so far its work pretty good. and has less collision. the index ranges from 0 - 300 maybe even more than that, but i haven't gotten any higher so far even with long words like "electromechanical engineering"

```
int keyHash(string key)
{
    unsigned int k = (int)key.length();
    unsigned int u = 0,n = 0;

    for (Uint i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        n = (int)key[i];
        u += 7*n%31;
    }
    return u%139;
}
```

another thing you can do is multiplying each character int parse by the index as it increase like the word "bear"
(0*b) + (1*e) + (2*a) + (3*r) which will give you an int value to play with. the first hash function above collide at "here" and "hear" but still great at give some good unique values. the one below doesn't collide with "here" and "hear" because i multiply each character with the index as it increases.

```
int keyHash(string key)
{
    unsigned int k = (int)key.length();
    unsigned int u = 0,n = 0;

    for (Uint i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        n = (int)key[i];
        u += i*n%31;
    }
    return u%139;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple hash function that I use for a hash table I built. Its basically for taking a text file and stores every word in an index which represents the alphabetical order.

```
int generatehashkey(const char *name)
{
        int x = tolower(name[0])- 97;
        if (x < 0 || x > 25)
           x = 26;
        return x;
}
```

What this basically does is words are hashed according to their first letter. So, word starting with 'a' would get a hash key of 0, 'b' would get 1 and so on and 'z' would be 25. Numbers and symbols would have a hash key of 26. THere is an advantage this provides; You can calculate easily and quickly where a given word would be indexed in the hash table since its all in an alphabetical order, something like this:
Code can be found here: https://github.com/abhijitcpatil/general

> **Giving the following text as input:** Atticus said to Jem one day, “I’d rather you shot at tin cans in the backyard, but I know you’ll go
>   after birds. Shoot all the blue jays you want, if you can hit ‘em, but
>   remember it’s a sin to kill a mockingbird.” That was the only time I
>   ever heard Atticus say it was a sin to do something, and I asked Miss
>   Maudie about it. “Your father’s right,” she said. “Mockingbirds don’t
>   do one thing except make music for us to enjoy. They don’t eat up
>   people’s gardens, don’t nest in corn cribs, they don’t do one thing
>   but sing their hearts out for us. That’s why it’s a sin to kill a
>   mockingbird.

This would be the output:

```
0 --> a a about asked and a Atticus a a all after at Atticus
1 --> but but blue birds. but backyard
2 --> cribs corn can cans
3 --> do don’t don’t don’t do don’t do day
4 --> eat enjoy. except ever
5 --> for for father’s
6 --> gardens go
7 --> hearts heard hit
8 --> it’s in it. I it I it’s if I in
9 --> jays Jem
10 --> kill kill know
11 --> 
12 --> mockingbird. music make Maudie Miss mockingbird.”
13 --> nest
14 --> out one one only one
15 --> people’s
16 --> 17 --> right remember rather
18 --> sin sing said. she something sin say sin Shoot shot said
19 --> to That’s their thing they They to thing to time the That to the the tin to
20 --> us. up us
21 --> 
22 --> why was was want
23 --> 
24 --> you you you’ll you
25 --> 
26 --> “Mockingbirds ” “Your ‘em “I’d
```

Comment: A good hash function distributes the values equally across the buckets.