# Hashed Array Tips in C Language

Tags: c, hashtable

I need some ideas to develop a good hashing function for my assignment. I have a list of all the countries in the world (around 190) in total. The names of each country is the key for the hashing function. Is there a specific kind of hashing function anyone would recommend to store this data in a hashing function without many collisions? Also, can you perhaps give an example of how to implement it?

Comment: A similar question that might be of some help (java instead of c, but same principles apply) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings

Comment: ISO country codes - fits in an integer, guaranteed to be collision-free

Comment: @Erik: Very clever; if you made it an answer I'd upvote it.

Comment: @John: I don't think that really answers the OPs question though, I'll leave it a comment :P

Comment: You could write a pretty basic hashing function then write a test script (in your favorite scripting language) to see if there are any collisions. If you only have ~200 items in your data set, I doubt you have much to worry about.

Comment: Are the country names in English and ASCII?

Answer (score 2):

Use [GNU gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html).  For inputs like yours, it will generate C code for you which implements a perfect hash function (for the given inputs).  No collisions, no worries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generated perfect hash for that (GNU perf).

Of if the set of strings is dynamic then you can use ternary trie. 
For N unique strings it will give you unique number [1..N]. For your case it will be faster than with hash tables.
Here is my implementation of such thing:
http://code.google.com/p/tiscript/source/browse/trunk/tool/tl_ternary_tree.h

Comment: You should also point to [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), the ternary tree's easier to implement cousin.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach I can think of is for each country's name to compute the sum of the ASCII values in its representation and use this as the hash value:

```
int hash(const char *s)
{
    int h = 0;

    while (s && *s)
          h += *s++;

    return h;
}
```

If your hash map has size N, you store country names with `map[hash(my_country) % N] = my_country`. Conceptually.

Just try this approach and see whether the resulting hash values are sufficiently uniformly distributed. Note that the quality of the distribution may also depend on N.