# Custom hashtable with distibuted values

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

I have some integer value like:

```
0, 2, 3, 1021, 2001, 2101, 3054 ...
```

Now, I want to put those values in a hash table. The integers are distributed like: every 1000 interval [means, 0-1000, 1000-2000 ...] has maximum 2-3 values.

Now, in my hash table I'm simply setting the bucket number with load factor 0.5. And hash code is simply: Integer % bucket number. However, it gives many collision.

Is there any better way to handle this type of particular distribution?

I have many files with such integers. So, setting fixed bucket number is impossible.

Comment: Why not use a standard HashMap? Does it give you as many collisions?

Comment: @assylias, it's slow and I could not handle it in my own way.

Comment: Setting a fixed bucket number is what happens when you completely ignore the number of buckets. The number of buckets increases if it isn't sufficient.

Comment: If standard hashmap is not an option, you might need to write your own implementation

Comment: @user1838343 You could at least try its rehashing strategy.

Comment: @tbodt, true. sorry, I forgot to mention, I know how many numbers are going to be inserted from the file size.

Answer (score 0):

[@asslysis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) is saying you have to create a your own hashing function
[GoodHashingFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings)
Good Hashing Function is necessary because if it is any duplicate key
it will replace value. See the code

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
public class HashMapKey {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hashtable a=new Hashtable();
    a.put("abc", 1000);
    a.put("abc", -1000);
    a.put("cde", 2000);
    System.out.println(a);
}

}
```

and output be {abc=-1000, cde=2000}

Comment: @user1838343 I think it will be ok you can also modify your load factor you can find useful link here [Hashfunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

Comment: @user1838343if you are still n trouble then comment.