# Convert UTF-8 string to alphanumeric string without information loss

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to use Jake Wharton's [DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache/) for Android to cache CouchDb documents on disk. CouchDb ids are just any JSON String, so could look `Sömething/Like/Thís`. However, the library's docs state

> Each cache entry has a string key and a fixed number of values. Each key must match the regex `[a-z0-9_-]{1,64}`.

So I need a way to transform an arbitrary strings to conform to the regex `[a-z0-9_-]{1,64}`, while still being unique. How can I do this elegantly?

Comment: Should the result still be (at least somewhat) readable? I mean, assuming mainly ASCII characters where used, should that be converted?

Comment: No, and I may also note: I do not have to be able to convert it back. So a hash should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about calculating a 64 character hash of the original JSON String and using this hash as a key for the cache?

But, this would not be guaranteed to be unique. But then again, mapping *any JSON String* to *[a-z0-9_-]{1,64}* will never be anyways.

Comment: True, true! So I would I generate this hash in Java?

Comment: Yes, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings for string hashing examples.

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa): you can convert the original string to a string representation of the hexidecimal representation of its bytes.

```
public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}
```

Although this might produce a String significantly larger than the previous, and may overflow 64-character limit.

Answer (score -1):

Using a hash is not feasible if you want to reverse it.
Base 64 doesn't match your requirements, but you can try something similar:

Encode each character using only [a-z0-9_-], or more exactly, if the character doesn't match [a-z0-9_], replace it by its unicode value preceeded by -.

Comment: is it a-z or a-zA-Z ? If you can use caps also, then just replace + and / by _ and -