# What is better to save a password in Android? Internal Storage or SQL database

Tags: android, sql

I am building an Android app that is password protected, but I am unsure where to save my password. Shall I use Internal Storage like an example below:

```
FileOutputStream foss = getActivity().openFileOutput(string,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                foss.write(password.getBytes());
                foss.close();
```

Or shall I use SQL Database?

What is more secure, and why? Or is there any other convenient method?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html is another way.

Comment: "I am unsure where to save my password" -- in the user's head, by having the user supply the passphrase.

Comment: If you're encrypting your data, don't store the password at all.  Use the (salted) password to generate the key.  Validate the password by trying to decrypt the data.

Comment: @petey can you please give me the implementation examples of cryptography?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with a SharedPreference. Since there is only one value and, no matter what system you are using, the user or a hacker can access it. As long as you [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) it, it should work fine. Hashing is basically one way encryption. While Hey might become abc Hiy might become 7h4. So every time the user enters a password, you hash the password the user has entered, and compare it to the hashed password in SharedPreferences, and if they match, grant the user access. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings) is a Stackoverflow thread about hashing in java.

EDIT: As comments have pointed out, [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html) is a very good way to hash passwords in android. Use this.

Comment: Can you tell me how to implement the Cryptography? I mean do you have any examples?

Comment: what about internal storage? I understand hashing is really safe but Shall I store password in internal storage or SharedPreference? and why?