# Thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3b1f8) while reading data from database and listing in listview using AES encryption?

Tags: java, android, listview, encryption

I was successful on ecrypting a string using AES and saving in the database. Now when the app starts it reads the database and list on the listview. As the strings are encrypted it has to be decrypt before showing in the listview. I worte the code and it seems to be ok but my apps crashes each time it is launched.

**AESHelper.java**

```
package protect.my.password;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.app.Activity;

public class AESHelper extends Activity{

       public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
               byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
               byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
               return toHex(result);
       }

       public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
               byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
               byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
               byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
               return new String(result);
       }

       private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
               KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
               SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
               sr.setSeed(seed);
           kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
           SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
           byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
           return raw;
       }


       private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
           SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
               Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
           byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
               return encrypted;
       }

       private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
           SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
               Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
           byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
               return decrypted;
       }

       public static String toHex(String txt) {
               return toHex(txt.getBytes());
       }
       public static String fromHex(String hex) {
               return new String(toByte(hex));
       }

       public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
               int len = hexString.length()/2;
               byte[] result = new byte[len];
               for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                       result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
               return result;
       }

       public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
               if (buf == null)
                       return "";
               StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
               for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                       appendHex(result, buf[i]);
               }
               return result.toString();
       }
       private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
       private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
               sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
       }


}
```

**ListView_read.java**

```
package protect.my.password;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


/**
 * Demo application to show how to use the 
 * built-in SQLite database with a cursor to populate
 * a ListView.
 */
public class ListView_read extends Activity {
    int[] imageIDs = {R.drawable.lock};
    int nextImageIndex = 0;
    String seedValue = "This Is MySecure";
    String diwas=DBAdapter.KEY_WEBSITE;
    String Website_decrypt;
    DBAdapter myDb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_read);

        openDB();
        populateListViewFromDB();
        registerListClickCallback();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();  
        closeDB();
    }

    private void openDB() {
        myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
        myDb.open();
    }
    private void closeDB() {
        myDb.close();
    }

    private void populateListViewFromDB() {
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

        // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
        // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        diwas();
        // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {Website_decrypt, DBAdapter.KEY_STUDENTNUM};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.item_name,     R.id.item_icon};

        // Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elementt in the UI.



        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this,       // Context
                        R.layout.item_layout,   // Row layout template
                        cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                        fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                        toViewIDs, // View IDs to put information in
                        1
                        );

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFromDB);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }

    private void diwas() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                Website_decrypt = AESHelper.decrypt(seedValue, diwas);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
}
```

Any idea why my app is crashing?

**Logcat**

```
08-05 08:49:11.425: D/dalvikvm(2363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 76K, 5% free 3135K/3276K, paused 31ms, total 34ms
08-05 08:49:11.475: W/System.err(2363): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "we"
08-05 08:49:11.485: W/System.err(2363):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
08-05 08:49:11.485: W/System.err(2363):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
08-05 08:49:11.485: W/System.err(2363):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
08-05 08:49:11.495: W/System.err(2363):     at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:509)
08-05 08:49:11.495: W/System.err(2363):     at protect.my.password.AESHelper.toByte(AESHelper.java:72)
08-05 08:49:11.495: W/System.err(2363):     at protect.my.password.AESHelper.decrypt(AESHelper.java:29)
08-05 08:49:11.495: W/System.err(2363):     at protect.my.password.ListView_read.diwas(ListView_read.java:87)
08-05 08:49:11.495: W/System.err(2363):     at protect.my.password.ListView_read.populateListViewFromDB(ListView_read.java:59)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at protect.my.password.ListView_read.onCreate(ListView_read.java:35)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-05 08:49:11.505: W/System.err(2363):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 08:49:11.515: D/AndroidRuntime(2363): Shutting down VM
08-05 08:49:11.515: W/dalvikvm(2363): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4aa9ba8)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363): Process: protect.my.password, PID: 2363
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{protect.my.password/protect.my.password.ListView_read}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteCursor.java:178)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:301)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:333)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:107)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at protect.my.password.ListView_read.populateListViewFromDB(ListView_read.java:69)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at protect.my.password.ListView_read.onCreate(ListView_read.java:35)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-05 08:49:11.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2363):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace

Comment: @DeepakBala You mean log cat? Yeap I posted it. Could you help me figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace is quite clear

> Invalid int: "we"

"we" cannot be converted to it's equivalent integer in radix 16. You are attempting to parse it as an integer on this line. `w` comes after `f`.

`result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();`

Your code appears to be related to an earlier question - [What is better to save a password in Android? Internal Storage or SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127944/what-is-better-to-save-a-password-in-android-internal-storage-or-sql-database)

You're better off asking the user for the password or storing it offline (not on the device). Your code can be reverse engineered anytime and rooted devices have access to shared preferences and databases.

Comment: Anyway, I still didn't understand your answer. I know rooted phone can have access to database that is why I want to encrypt the database. Can you give me any recommendation on this topic? New biee here. And can you recommend me what encryption method to use and the implementation examples.

Comment: `w` is not a hexadecimal character. You cannot convert it. Your question was on why your program crashed and I've answered it. If you'd like to ask a separate question, please do so by creating a new one.

Comment: You said the encryption can be reverse engineered. I made the above code work and encryption also works. But it is AES encryption, if it can be reverse engineered, than why shall people use it?