# What are some good hash functions for getting hash values of a string in Java?

Tags: java, function, hash

I am looking for two hash functions for hashing strings in Java. Can anyone suggest some functions that are already written in Java for this? I already looked [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed) but I am not sure how to implement them in Java. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `String.hashCode`?  What requirements do you have that it doesn't meet?

Comment: If you can use external libraries, go with Guava and its [`Hashing`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html) class

Comment: I am looking for other sources that aren't included with java to test on my application.

Comment: What are you trying to use this hash for?  A `HashMap`?  A security application?  A Bloom filter?  It matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Hash Function for Strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings)

Comment: Thanks everyone. That "Good Hash Function for Strings" thread was helpful. I ended up going with the DJB function and the Murmur function from here: https://code.google.com/r/sergiobossa-terrastore-kryo/source/browse/src/main/java/terrastore/router/impl/?r=38f6dd91cd36e1c7386e966c1e4c0a8aa909e3a4