# Is this a viable way to encrypt and decrypt strings?

Tags: java, security

I had this idea while in health class to try to encrypt and decrypt strings using something irreversable; Random. The problem with encrypting data is that people can usually decrypt it from the final encrypted version. In my example I believe it is not possible, because the random number that represents the encrypted version uses a seed made by the hash of the original un-encrypted string to make it. It's not possible to take a number and figure out what seed was used to get it from a random as far as I know, so that should make this 100% un-decryptable. Can you guys tell me if there are any flaws in this before I put it to use if there is? Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String hey1 = encrypt("hey");
    System.out.println(decrypt(hey1,"hey"));
    System.out.println(decrypt(hey1,"this won't work"));
}

public static String encrypt(String s) {
    return new Random(s.hashCode()).nextFloat()+"";

}

public static boolean decrypt(String encrypted, String original) {
    String encryptednew = encrypt(original);
    if (encrypted.equals(encryptednew))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you want no one to be able to decrypt your data, just delete it.

Comment: Encryption suggests that you can unencrypt it. What you are creating, if it cannot be restored to it's original, I believe is a hash. This can be useful for checking if a password is the same.

Comment: It's not encryption. It's hashing(and a bad one - not reproducible on next run, because same Objects can have different hashCodes in different executions). Your code is a bit confusing. Why does it say `decrypt` when it in fact just checks the hash?

Comment: Encrypting a string by passing the "orignal data" as key is pretty... pointless?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Hash Function for Strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings)

Comment: You aren't encrypting anything, you're hashing it.  There is no way to go from the result of `encrypt` to anything useful.

Comment: The default hash has an easily readable pattern and is easy to decrypt. so.... is this a good advanced hash?

Comment: I made the function called decrypt cuz i wrote it out on paper

Comment: It would be for something like if a user created an account and it saved the encrypted password and when they log in they check the encrypted password and then the one they typed

Comment: gopro: `s.hashCode()` can(and most propobably will) yield different result when you restart your program.

Comment: One could get into an argument about how "cryptographically strong" random() is.   There is also SecureRandom which is supposed to be much cryptographically stronger.   *I* have no idea how one would reverse engineer random(), but if it was *impossible* there would be no need for a "better" function, so one might infer that it's possible.

Comment: Your hash is a little worse than java's "hashcode" implementation on String. Why? You are using that to seed the random. Therefore it will return the very Same value, everytime the seed is equal, since you are allways using a NEW random object. hashCode returns a 64-bit long, your random generates a float (32 bit) out of it. Thus, you would have some long-inputs leading to the same random number, so your are generating less different hash-values.

Comment: `Random` is not actually very secure, by which I mean it's not actually that difficult to reverse, so no.

Comment: Please, before you implement anything like this in any real system, read this question and answer: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Comment: I want to think Louis Wasserman and dognose for actually answering my question. All the rest of you didn't help one bit but criticize the obvoius

Comment: Also btw hash code will NOT I REPEAT NOT return different results. using this code, it always works even after restarting my pc `String hey1 = encrypt("hey");
  if ("0.010719538".equals(hey1)) {
   System.out.println("Yes!");
  }`

Comment: If this is for serious use, then use a proven [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) instead of trying to craft your own.

Answer (score 3):

Encryption suggests that you can unencrypt it. What you are creating, if it cannot be restored to it's original, I believe is a hash. This can be useful for checking if a password is the same, but not for sending secret messages.

Equally, this is "un-decryptable":

```
public String encrypt(String input){

    return "Boo";

}
```

This is true because given the String "Boo", you cannot tell what the input was.
Creating a hash however is useful for passwords, and a hash is something which can be verified. For example, if a password is sent to a server, instead of storing the raw password, a hash is stored. Next time the password is sent to the server, it can calculate the hash and see if it's the same as the stored one. For a sensible level of security, salts are also needed, and that's something I would recommend looking up.