# How to get same string generated by pseudo random generator with some initialized string?

Tags: java, string, random

How to get same string generated by pseudo random generator with some initialized string in java. I want something like this

I get this code from somewhere. It produces fine random string but what I want is that whenever I pass some string let suppose "Name" with it, it gives me the same random string generated with this function. Means I want same random string with "Name".

```
public static String RandomAlphaNumericString(int numChars)
{
    char[] All = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456879".toCharArray();
    SecureRandom srand = new SecureRandom();
    Random rand = new Random();
    char[] buff = new char[numChars];
    for (int i = 0; i < numChars; ++i) {
        // reseed rand once you've used up all available entropy bits
        if ((i % 10) == 0) {
          rand.setSeed(srand.nextLong()); // 64 bits of random!
        }
        buff[i] = All[rand.nextInt(All.length)];
    }
    return new String(buff);
}
```

Comment: So, you want a method that will shuffle the characters in the string?

Comment: `new SecureRandom(string.getBytes())` ?

Comment: don't capitalize variable names

Comment: do you mean that if "Name" is passed in, you want strings like "aNme", "mNae", "eamN" etc ??

Comment: I want that if I pass same string generated by random generator with initial substring "Name" that will result in a same string e.g Randomstring1 = Namejs234mnsd34 and Randomstring2 = Namejs234mnsd34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a random string then if you want predictable results based on input.  What you want is a hash if you want the same encoded key returned each time.  If you also want to decrypt the encoded key, then you want encryption rather than hashing.  Try researching how to hash a string, e.g. [see this previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings).

Comment: Yes I have to use a hash for this purpose. Thanks.