# How to map 256 unique strings to the integers (0..255) with a memory-free function

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, function, hash

Say I have strings like `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `hello`, `world`, etc. up to 256 unique strings, so not very many. It could just as easily be 200 strings or 32 strings for all intents and purposes. Hopefully the solution could handle arbitrarily sized sets.

So you take that string and somehow map it to an integer 0-255. Without just doing this:

```
strings[currentString] = ID++
// strings['foo'] = 0
// strings['bar'] = 1
// strings['baz'] = 2
// ...
```

which would depend on the *order* they are inserted. Ideally they would be generated uniquely perhaps from a hash of the individual characters or bytes somehow, I'm not sure. But it would be a function *without memory* that takes an arbitrary string from a set of known size and maps it to an integer, so more like:

```
// strings['foo'] = 6 + 15 + 15 = 36
// strings['bar'] = 2 + 1 + 16 = 19
// ...
```

Although that wouldn't work because of collisions. I'm not sure how to go about designing a hash function like this. So somehow something else would work where there are *never collisions* to worry about.

```js
function hash(string, size) {
  // return unique integer within size
}

hash('foo', 256) // something like 123
hash('bar', 256) // something like 101

hash('foo', 100) // something else like 50
hash('bar', 100) // something else like 25
```

I would be interested to know too generally how to go about creating such a function, because it seems very difficult, but not strictly necessary for the question.

Also, looking to do this with basic JavaScript, not any special helper methods or browser-specific stuff.

The set of possible strings is known in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good Hash Function for Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188027/discussion-on-question-by-lance-pollard-how-to-map-256-unique-strings-to-256-uni).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe what you're looking for is possible unless you know what all 256 strings are ahead of time. Roughly, here's a proof of this:

Suppose there exists some `f : S^* → [0, 255]` (note: `S^*` means all finite length strings) s.t. for all 256-length subsets `S ⊆ S^*`, `s_1, s_2 ∈ S, f(s_1) = f(s_2) <=> s_1 = s_2`. Since `f` must not hold any memory of inputs it has seen, it must deterministically map strings to the same number in `[0, 255]`, regardless of what subset this is in.

However, by the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), since there are more than 256 strings, we must have at least two strings that map to the same value between `[0, 255]`. In particular, this means that if we take a subset `S` that contains both strings, the above property for `f` is violated, a contradiction. Thus, `f` cannot exist.

---

If you are allowed to know which 256 strings to hash, this is definitely possible. In general, what you're looking for is a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

This link provides an algorithm: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect1004.pdf (refer to pages 56-57)

Quoting:

> **Method 1: an `O(N^2)`-space solution**
>
> Say we are willing to have a table whose size is quadratic in the size
>   `N` of our dictionary `S`. Then, here is an easy method for
>   constructing a perfect hash function. Let `H` be universal and
>   `M=N^2`. Then just pick a random `h` from `H` and try it out! The
>   claim is there is at least a 50% chance it will have no collisions.
>
> **Method 2: an `O(N)`-space solution**
>
> We will first hash into a table of size `N` using universal hashing.
>   This will produce some collisions (unless we are extraordinarily
>   lucky). However, we will then rehash each bin using Method 1, squaring
>   the size of the bin to get zero collisions. So, the way to think of
>   this scheme is that we have a first-level hash function `h` and
>   first-level table `A`, and then `N` second-level hash functions
>   `h_1, ..., h_N` and `N` second-level tables `A_1, ..., A_N`. To
>   lookup an element `x`, we first compute `i=h(x)` and then find the
>   element in `A_i[h_i(x)]`.

Comment: Doesn't your proposal require memory? OP said, "it would be a function without memory."

Comment: OP stated in a comment that "If you must have a memory, then knowing how to do it like that will be okay." As I've mentioned in my answer, this problem isn't solvable without *some* memory usage (assuming you want some reasonable runtime).

Comment: This problem is definitely solvable for some inputs. I just solved it for the OP's example input.

Answer (score 3):

> Without just doing this: […] which would depend on the *order* they are inserted.

> The set of possible strings is known in advance.

If you're fine with requiring the strings to be known upfront, but you just don't like the arbitrariness of using the order in which they happen to have been inserted, then one simple approach is to gather the strings into an array, sort that array (to get a deterministic ordering), and then use the resulting order:

```
var stringArray = [];
stringArray.push('foo');
stringArray.push('bar');
stringArray.push('baz');
// ...
stringArray = stringArray.sort();

var strings = {};
for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; ++i) {
    strings[stringArray[i]] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of an idea that could have good results for a variety of inputs. The code below assumes lowercase english letters, no spaces, and only allows for up to 9 duplicates of any letter.

The idea is that any permutation of length `n` can be mapped to the integers modulo `n` by detecting how many times the permutation must be applied to itself before transforming into the identity permutation. Its "power" if you will. The catch is that any permutations with the same permutation cycles (the unordered integer partition that describes them), will result in the same "power", which we are using as the final hash.

To generate the permutation, each letter is assigned to one of nine buckets of 26, depending on if it's a duplicate, and pushed to an array, followed by the missing indexes from 0 to 255.

Like many hash functions, this can result in collisions (which could possibly be ameliorated through a few flags set in the function based on input analysis, although I have yet to consider that more carefully).

```js
function seq(n){
  return [...Array(n)].map((_,i) => i);
}

function permute(p1, p){
  return p1.map(x => p[x]);
}

function areEqual(p1, p){
  for (let i=0; i<p.length; i++)
    if (p1[i] != p[i])
      return false;
  return true;
}

function findPower(p1){
  let count = 0;
  const p = seq(p1.length);
  let p2 = p1.slice();
  for (let i=0; i<p.length; i++){
    if (!areEqual(p, p2)){
      p2 = permute(p2, p1);
      count++;
    } else {
      return count;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

// Returns the permutation based on
// the string, s
function hash(s){
  // Each letter is in one of
  // 9 buckets of 26, depending
  // on if it's a duplicate.
  let fs = new Array(26).fill(0);
  let result = [];
  for (let i=0; i<s.length; i++){
    let k = s.charCodeAt(i) - 97;
    result.push(26 * fs[k] + k);
    fs[k]++;
  }
  const set = new Set(result);
  for (let i=0; i<256; i++)
    if (!set.has(i))
      result.push(i);

  return result;
}

function h(s){
  return findPower(hash(s));
}

var strings = [
  'foo',
  'bar',
  'baz',
  'hello',
  'world',
  'etc'];

for (let s of strings)
  console.log(`${ s }: ${ h(s) }`);
```

Comment: This is amazing! I would love to know more behind your thought process on how you figured this out. I knew about permutations but only as an introductory amount, I couldn't figure out the stuff you're describing, you seem to have a much deeper grasp.

Comment: @LancePollard heh, thanks. It's a nice brain tease but with a lot of varying data, this implementation could see quite a few collisions. (At least that could be assessed in advance and possibly extended to account for.) (For practical use I'd consider ruakh's trivial idea, although the question makes me wonder why you'd look for such a method in the first place.) I don't know how I figured it out, lol - I guess I had the idea, "what if we could map a sequence or something about the sequence of a very limited string," and it somehow led me to reading about permutation groups.