# Elasticsearch manipulate existing field value to add new field

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to add new field which is value comes from hashed existing field value. So, i want to do;
my_index.hashedusername(new field) = crc32(my_index.username) (existing field)

For example

```
POST  _update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script" : {
      "source": "ctx._source.hashedusername = crc32(ctx._source.username);"
  }
}
```

Please give me an idea how to do this..

Comment: Do you want to update existing docs or are you looking for a solution to add that hashed field upon ingestion?

Comment: I want to update existing docs with new field (hashedusername)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.zip.CRC32` is not available in the [shared painless API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference-shared.html) so mocking that package will be non-trivial -- perhaps even unreasonable.

I'd suggest to compute the CRC32 hashes beforehand and only then send the docs to ES. Alternatively, [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html) through all your documents, compute the hash and bulk-update your documents.

The painless API was designed to perform comparatively simple tasks and CRC32 is certainly outside of its purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have 400 M document. So manually change is hard for me. Do you know any other way to add new field which is hold unique hash code?

Comment: No prob. Perhaps this would help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2624192/8160318