# How to generate hash number of a string in Go?

Tags: hash, go

For example:

```
hash("HelloWorld") = 1234567
```

Is there any built-in function could do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not Go specific but interesting and related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/107657/532430

Comment: that's known as prehash, theoretically.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The [hash](http://golang.org/pkg/hash/) package is helpful for this. Note it's an abstraction over specific hash implementations. Some ready made are found in the package [subdirectories](http://golang.org/pkg/hash/#pkg-subdirectories).

Example:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "hash/fnv"
)

func hash(s string) uint32 {
        h := fnv.New32a()
        h.Write([]byte(s))
        return h.Sum32()
}

func main() {
        fmt.Println(hash("HelloWorld"))
        fmt.Println(hash("HelloWorld."))
}
```

(Also [here](http://play.golang.org/p/_J2YysdEqE))

---

Output:

```
926844193
107706013
```

Comment: Also, it's possible to use single instance and `Write`/`Reset`, instead of creating `New32a` every time. I don't know how much it's cost. For example: https://play.golang.org/p/aUeNBo755g

Comment: Are these hashes unique? can i use it as a unique identifier?

Comment: These hashes are not very unique. The chances of two different strings matching the same uint32 are approximately 1 to 4 billion. I would not use it for uniqueness. Here is an example which may prove more useful: every task has a unique "string", and I would like to uniformly distribute the tasks between 50 queues. I would do (with the above function) hash("HelloWorld") % 50.

Comment: This is a bad method, 797186 and 40189 has the same hash: 270439499

Comment: @iwind Every hash function into a smaller space (like arbitrary-length string into uint32 here) is guaranteed to have collisions so "I found one specific collision" is not an argument for whether a method is good or bad. If you analyzed the method and found a high collision rate or nonuniform distribution or some other meaningful flaw that would be a compelling argument, but I imagine such analyses already exist for FNV.

Comment: @Backgammon ok, i agree with you.

Comment: @IvanBlack I wonder about the concurrency and race condition issues when using that same New32a instance in each call to getHash. In my mind, two simultaneous getHash function calls could interleave in a way that results in one of them Resetting the other's Write before it does a Sum call, giving a result you wouldn't want.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a function you could use to generate a hash number:

```
// FNV32a hashes using fnv32a algorithm
func FNV32a(text string) uint32 {
    algorithm := fnv.New32a()
    algorithm.Write([]byte(text))
    return algorithm.Sum32()
}
```

I put together a group of those utility hash functions here: https://github.com/shomali11/util

You will find `FNV32`, `FNV32a`, `FNV64`, `FNV64a`, `MD5`, `SHA1`, `SHA256` and `SHA512`