# How to hash very large substrings quickly without collisions?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, hash

I have an app which as part of it finds all palindrome substrings of the input string. The input string can be up to 100,000 in length so the substrings can be  very large. For example one input to the app resulted in over 300,000 substring palindromes over 10,000 in length. The app later counts all palindromes for equality and counts the unique ones by a hash that uses the standard hash that is done in the function that finds the palindromes. The hashes are stored in a vector and later counted for uniqueness in the app. The problems with such input and outptut conditions is the hashing for the very large substrings takes too long plus gets collisions in the hashes. So I was wondering if there is an algorithm (hash) that can quickly and uniquely hash a very large substring (preferably by index range for the substring for speed, but with accuracy for uniqueness). The hashing is done at the end of the function get_palins. The code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctgmath>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 100000
#define mod 1000000007

vector<long long> palins[MAX+5];

//  Finds all palindromes for the string
void  get_palins(string &s)
{
     int N = s.length();
     int i, j, k,   // iterators
     rp,        // length of 'palindrome radius'
     R[2][N+1]; // table for storing results (2 rows for odd- and even-length palindromes

     s = "@" + s + "#"; // insert 'guards' to iterate easily over s

     for(j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
     {
         R[j][0] = rp = 0; i = 1;

         while(i <= N)
         {
             while(s[i - rp - 1] == s[i + j + rp]) {  rp++;  }
             R[j][i] = rp;
             k = 1;
             while((R[j][i - k] != rp - k) && (k < rp))
             {
                 R[j][i + k] = min(R[j][i - k],rp - k);
                 k++;
             }
             rp = max(rp - k,0);
             i += k;
         }
     }

     s = s.substr(1,N); // remove 'guards'

     for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
     {
        for(j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
            for(rp = R[j][i]; rp > 0; rp--)
            {
                int begin = i - rp - 1;
                int end_count = 2 * rp + j;
                int end = begin + end_count - 1;
                if (!(begin == 0  && end == N -1 ))
                {
                   string ss = s.substr(begin, end_count);
                   long long hsh = hash<string>{}(ss);
                   palins[begin].push_back(hsh);

                }
          }
     }
}
unordered_map<long long, int> palin_counts;
unordered_map<char, int> end_matches;

// Solve when at least 1 character in string is different
void solve_all_not_same(string &s)
{
    int n = s.length();
    long long count = 0;

    get_palins(s);

    long long palin_count = 0;

    // Gets all palindromes into unordered map
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (auto& it : palins[i])
        {
            if (palin_counts.find(it)  == palin_counts.end())
            {
                palin_counts.insert({it,1});
            }
            else
            {
                palin_counts[it]++;
            }
        }
    }

    // From total palindromes, get proper border count
    // minus end characters of substrings
    for ( auto it = palin_counts.begin(); it != palin_counts.end(); ++it )
    {
        int top = it->second - 1;

        palin_count += (top * (top + 1)) / 2;
        palin_count %= mod;
    }

    // Store string character counts in unordered map
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        char c = s[i];

        //long long hsh = hash<char>{}(c);

        if (end_matches[c] == 0)
            end_matches[c] = 1;
        else
            end_matches[c]++;

    }

    // From substring end character matches, get proper border count
    // for end characters of substrings
    for ( auto it = end_matches.begin(); it != end_matches.end(); it++ )
    {
        int f = it->second - 1;
        count += (f * (f + 1)) / 2;
    }

    cout << (count + palin_count) % mod << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX+5; i++)
        palins[i].clear();
}

int main()
{

    string s; 
    cin >> s;

    solve_all_not_same(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure its just the hashing that is the bottleneck here ? Just from scanning through the above code, I see quite a few inefficient stuff going on. For eg: adding suffix and prefix to an already large string plus lots of extra substring copies which I am not sure but can be definitely avoided if you use a pair of values indicating the start and end position within the string.

Comment: Also, `R[2][N+1]` is not standard C++. It may  work for you for your platform...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98153/whats-the-best-hashing-algorithm-to-use-on-a-stl-string-when-using-hash-map might be a possible solution. Also, if you can add some smartness (the update hash what we do in rabin-karp) in addition to that, you can probably get a huge speedup.

Comment: @Arunmu The code is for checking for proper palindromic borders of substrings. That's why the prefix and suffix calculations. I need to identify each unique palindrome by hash. In the code it later updates the unordered mapped by hash from the vector. I tried using an unordered map in the first place instead of the vector but since an insert to the map requires a lookup for  duplicates I didn't see a performance improvement. Also the R[2][N+1] works in Eclipse but not in Visual Studio. Thanks for the link to hashing post. I was thinking the bottleneck was the call to string "substr".

Comment: > I was thinking the bottleneck was the call to string "substr".  Just storing the start and end position of the interested substring would help ?

Comment: In the "get_palins" function it is supposed to uniquely identify identical hashes. The same palindrome substring that appears at 2 different times should have the same hash value. Then later after the map of hashes totals the count for each unique hash, that is used to identify substrings that have matching palindromes at the end of the substring and at the beginning of the substring. Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/palindromic-border. I used the murmur3 hash from the link you provided and that helped. Thanks. But still getting collisions on hashes

Comment: I have a solution based on my above comments which does zero string copying while processing and also doesn't make use of hash. I may have missed a condition to check, but this approach should be way efficient and also provides nice abstraction with zero cost :).  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afcf7146b9a6a0a0

Comment: Also there is another huge optimization win for long runs of same character which I have not implemented.

Comment: (There's a typo in the title.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced with problem *X* (*find all palindrome substrings*), you ask how to solve *Y* (*hash substrings quickly*): [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).
For palindrome detection, consider suffix arrays (one for the reverse of the input, or that appended to the input).
For fast hashes of overlapping strings, look into [rolling hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash).

Comment: Belatedly, I found te7's comment containing a link to a HackerRank problem: Dissimilar in the constraints, and the explanation of the first sample output contradicts the first statement of that output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I appreciate it. I solved the problem using the Murmur3 hash 64x128. I will look into those links. Thanks

Comment: For string matching try the _Rabin-Karp rolling hash_.